# Noobie needs help on designing database for membership management tool

Tags: mysql, database-design, relations

I have searched through some of the database examples, but have yet to wrap my head around the logic of the relations between databases, so appreciate some support. Here is what I am trying to do: for a non-profit organisation (German Kindergarden), I am trying to set up a membership management tool/database. Here is what it needs to do:

- store member details (name, address, etc): these are usually one or two parents
- Record children details: the children in the kindergarden
- Provide general information about members and children via queries/reports

Provide an overview over memberships: a membership is family based (one family one membership) and can contain one or more members as well as one or more children.

The membership shall then record things like the membership fee and if there is a bank account linked already as well as start and end date.

I need to be able to enter:

- new members
- new children
- and obviously new memberships.

In my view, this should contain 3 tables:

| Members | Children | Memberships |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MemberID | ChildID | MembershipID |
| MembershipID (FK) | MembershipID (FK) | Name |
| Last Name | Last Name | Fee |
| First Name | First Name | StartDate |
| etc. | etc. | EndDate |
|  |  |  |

My idea is to use the "Membership" table to rule them all. The name of the membership should be equal to the family name of the child. (am I missing a relationship here? probably...)

Now my questions:

- Am I on the right track with the general setup?
- If so, how would I go about creating these databases? I am pretty tool agnostic, but would prefer working with pure SQL. MySQL WOrkbench could work too.
- How would I 'link' the /name/ of the membership to any of the child's last name?
- I have the data for members and children stored already. How do I 'import' them into the tables? I guess it makes sense to first populate 'members' and 'children' and then 'create the 'memberships'?

Sorry if this is really basic stuff, but would appreciate some help to point me in the right direction.
Cheers, mor3dr3ad

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Two things - find an/some Open Source membership system(s) and check out how they do it! Also, especially with children's data, make sure that you have GDPR covered - ensure encryption is performed at a database and/or a disk level. – `member - MembershipID (FK)` - remove the FK here - what's this pointing at? `membership_id` is inherent to the `member` so it doesn't go into a separate table - having it as an FK in the `child` table on the other hand makes perfect sense!

Comment: hey verace, thanks a lot. how can membership_id be inherent to member? remember that a membership is based on families, so two members and several children can be part of one membership..

Comment: Oops - I thought there was one "primary" member and then children (and possibly spouses)?